# How to improve this code for replacing elements of a matrix from another matrices in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

So I have these 4 same-sized matrices:

```
k = [0.5; 1.0; 1.5; 2.0];
l = [2; 4; 6; 8];
m = [1.7; 3.0; 4.5; 6.0];
n = [2.5; 5.0; 7.5; 10.0];
```

And I want to put the elements from each matrix into the diagonal of zero matrix, so it would create something like this:

```
f =  0.5 2.0 0   0   0   0   0   0 
     1.7 2.5 0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   1.0 4.0 0   0   0   0  
     0   0   3.0 5.0 0   0   0   0  
     0   0   0   0   1.5 6.0 0   0  
     0   0   0   0   4.5 7.5 0   0  
     0   0   0   0   0   0   2.0 8.0
     0   0   0   0   0   0   6.0 10.0
```

This is what I've come up with:

```
f = zeros(8,8);
k = [0.5; 1.0; 1.5; 2.0];
l = [2; 4; 6; 8];
m = [1.7; 3.0; 4.5; 6.0];
n = [2.5; 5.0; 7.5; 10.0];

for i = 1:2:8 %odd index number
    for j = 2:2:8 %even index number
        f(i,i) = k(1,i)
        f(i,j) = l(1,i)
        f(j,i) = m(1,i)
        f(j,j) = n(i,1)
    end;
end;
disp(f)
```

But the result put the elements not into the diagonal of matrix `f=zero(8,8)`, and I've always got the error of `Index exceeds matrix dimensions.`

Can I get some pointers on how to fix this code?

Comment: Irrelevant to your question though I still want to point this out. `k`, `l`, `m` and `n` are vectors (1D arrays). You only need to specify one index to access the value, i.e. `k(i)` instead of `k(1,i)`.

Comment: And on top of what @anthony said: `k(1,i)` is out of bounds because it is a column vector, and the first index is the row number. Try `k(i,1)` instead. But just as an exercise to learn about indexing. `k(i)` is easier and more idiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

I think you intended to write this:

```
for i = 2:2:8
    f(i-1,i-1) = k(i/2)
    f(i-1,i) = l(i/2)
    f(i,i-1) = m(i/2)
    f(i,i) = n(i/2)
end
```

Though there must be simpler ways to accomplish the same thing. For example, check out the function [`blkdiag`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/blkdiag.html)!

Comment: `k((i+1)/2)` and same for others :)

Comment: I think I got it now, thank you so much for the help! I will checkout the `blkdiag` function too, to make this code a bit simpler!

Comment: @Anthony: Absolutely right! I did not at all pay attention writing that, did I? :)

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for compact, then here's an interesting solution using [`eye`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eye.html), [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html), and [logical indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1):

```
>> f = zeros(8);
>> f(repelem(eye(4, 'logical'), 2, 2)) = [k m l n].';

f =

    0.5000    2.0000         0         0         0         0         0         0
    1.7000    2.5000         0         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0    1.0000    4.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0    3.0000    5.0000         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0    1.5000    6.0000         0         0
         0         0         0         0    4.5000    7.5000         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0         0    2.0000    8.0000
         0         0         0         0         0         0    6.0000   10.0000
```

Comment: This one is nice! I knew people would come up with really short answers to this. :) Somehow I was hoping `kron` would be part of the solution, but I don't see how...

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Check my edit. I used `kron` at first, but changed to `repelem` because I think it is more efficient.

Comment: Ah, there was a `kron` in there! Awesome! I'm going to have to learn to use that at some point... :p

Comment: This one is really nice and efficient! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Cris Luengo's answer is more flexible and read much better than what I have here, but this is something you probably want to learn if you will do a lot of work using MATLAB.

*(This method generally performs better because it removes the need of a `for` loop.)*

```
k = [0.5;1.0;1.5;2.0];
l = [2;4;6;8];
m = [1.7;3.0;4.5;6.0];
n = [2.5;5.0;7.5;10.0];

f = zeros(8); % to create a square matrix, you only need to specify the size with one value

f(1:18:end) = k;
f(9:18:end) = l;
f(2:18:end) = m;
f(10:18:end) = n;
```

Here, `f` is used as if it is a vector (array) even though it is a 8*8 matrix. In Matlab, you can access a single element from a matrix by either specifying the row and column number or linear indexing.

*More details can be found here: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html (see Linear Indexing)*

Comment: @Wolfie true. I previously wanted to demonstrate the idea in more details thus had `idx_k = 1:18:nf;` etc...  Later I decided to simplify the code and didn't realise that `nf` was also made redunant. answer revised.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to construct the diagonal, and the two off-diagonal vectors first and then use `diag` to create the matrices and then adding them together.

```
%Data
k = [0.5;1.0;1.5;2.0];
l = [2;4;6;8];
m = [1.7;3.0;4.5;6.0];
n = [2.5;5.0;7.5;10.0];

%Construct vectors
diagonal = [1;0].*k.' + [0;1].*n.'; %Diagonal of the matrix
offu = [1;0].*l'; %Upper diagonal
offl = [1;0].*m'; %Lower diagonal

A = diag(diagonal(:)) + diag(offu(1:end-1),1) + diag(offl(1:end-1),-1);
```

I have no idea whether it is faster than the other answers, but I like its transparency of what is happening.

NOTE: In order to construct the variables `diagonal`, `offu` and `offl` I am using implicit expansion which requires Matlab R2016b or newer. If you are using an older version, you can instead use `bsxfun`.

Answer (score 1):

A sorry, I missed the everything is shifted. My former answer was completely incorrect...

I still would go for something with blkdiag, you just need to redistribute your matrices:

```
k = [0.5; 1.0; 1.5; 2.0];
l = [2; 4; 6; 8];
m = [1.7; 3.0; 4.5; 6.0];
n = [2.5; 5.0; 7.5; 10.0];

Y = arrayfun(@(i) [k(i), l(i); m(i), n(i)], 1:4, 'UniformOutput', false);
blkdiag(Y{:})

X = cat(3, [k, m], [l, n]);
blkdiag(squeeze(X(1,:,:)), squeeze(X(2,:,:)), squeeze(X(3,:,:)), squeeze(X(4,:,:)))
```

Comment: This does not give the desired result as shown in the question... Each block is not a single vector, rather each corresponding element within a block is from the same vector

Comment: Sorry @Wolfie, that is true. Fixed.